# Convert string into timestamp in Hive

Tags: datetime, hadoop, hive, impala, timestamp-with-timezone

I have a value '2017-09-27T19:25:15.927-07:00', is there any way to convert this into a timestamp? 
I use Hive 1.1.0.

`select unix_timestamp("2017-09-27T19:25:15.927-07:00", "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSSX")` but it trows `Bad date/time conversion format`

`select unix_timestamp("2017-09-27T19:25:15.927-07:00", "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSSZZZ")` but it returns `NULL`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) is `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX"`.Note the single quotes surrounding 'T'

```
select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp("2017-09-27T19:25:15.927-07:00", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX"))
```