# Remove special character using hive

Tags: sql, hive, timestamp, hiveql

In a raw table, the date column has been saved in string format (e.g.,`2020-11-19T15:59:30.702+0000`).  I need to convert this to timestamp format(`2020-11-19 15:59:30.702`).

I tried with concat_ws `cast(concat_ws('.',from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(regexp_replace('2020-11-19T15:59:30.702+0000','T',''), 'yyyy-MM-ddHH:mm:ss')),REGEXP_REPLACE(split(createdat,'\\.')[1],'[^0-9A-Za-z ]+', ''))`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert string into timestamp in Hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46691877/convert-string-into-timestamp-in-hive)

Comment: @mck it is giving me null.    select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp("2020-11-19T15:59:30.702+0000", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX"));

Comment: Use `Z` instead of `XXX`

Comment: i tried   ---- select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp("2020-11-19T15:59:30.702+0000", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"));   but i am losing the miliseconds.

Comment: @mck Answer you provided as duplicate DOES NOT work with milliseconds because unix_timestamp returns seconds without milliseconds.

Comment: @leftjoin Thanks for reaching out. I tried with concat_ws ---   cast(concat_ws('.',from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(regexp_replace(createdat,'T',''), 'yyyy-MM-ddHH:mm:ss')),REGEXP_REPLACE(split(createdat,'\\.')[1],'[^0-9A-Za-z ]+', ''))

Comment: @leftjoin is there anyway we can store the whole string (2020-11-19T15:59:30.702+0000) as timestamp?

Comment: For LasySimpleSerDe  (Stored AS TEXTFILE) it is possible to specify different timestamp format which will be deserialized as normal timestamp: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58501775/2700344 Try "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'+0000'" Not sure will it work with other SerDe or not. Check it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not need timezone conversion (if it is always +0000 timezone), remove T and timezone:

```
 select timestamp(regexp_replace("2020-11-19T15:59:30.702+0000", '^(.+?)T(.+?)\\+','$1 $2'));
```

Result:

```
2020-11-19 15:59:30.702
```